# User Authentication if Admin or User laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently new to Laravel. This is my fist time building with this framework. I 'm trying to create a login. It was easy by running the `php artisan make:auth` command however i'm trying to determine if the user that was login is regular user or admin?

```php
$table->boolean('is_admin')->nullable();
```

I've tried to add that to my `user` model to determine if user is admin or not and try to modify my `LoginController` by adding this code.

```php
public function determineTypeLogin(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user()->is_admin;

    if ($user == 1) {
        return "admin";
    }

    return "not admin";
}
```

however no luck.. Please help

Comment: what did you mean by __no luck__? any errors?

Comment: I was able to get through the Login page but it was not determined if the user is admin or not

Comment: you have added `is_admin`column to the table. but did you override the `RegisterUserController` to insert that  value when registering a new user?

Comment: Yes i did override it too. and put default value on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
public function determineTypeLogin(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user()->is_admin;

    if ($user == 1) {
        return "admin";
    }

    return "not admin";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to check `$user == 1` it return only tru or false so you can dirctly check like

public function determineTypeLogin(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user()->is_admin;

```
if ($user) {
    return "admin";
}

return "not admin";
```

}